# Trap handler not working?

Tags: bash, signals, trap, sigint

Is sth wrong with the following trap?

```
trap cleanup SIGINT

cleanup() {
            echo "Exiting script ..."
        }
```

I never see the `echo` command when hitting `Ctrl+c`

The snippet is at the bottom of a larger script having some infinite `while` loops.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this and testing it works as expected. Is the trap actually installed at the time when you press Ctrl+C?

Comment: For some reason, placing the snippet at the **top** of the script worked ... so this must be the case, it was not installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trap has to have been activated/installed at the time when you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, or it will (obviously) not trigger.  The function should also have been defined at that point.  This means moving the code up to the top (somewhere in the beginning) of your script.

Additionally, you should probably define the function *before* installing the trap, or you'll get a "not found" error if the trap is triggered in-between the two.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanup() { echo 'Exiting script ...'; }

trap cleanup SIGINT

sleep 300
```